# Union 2 queries to maximum show 5 search suggestions

Tags: php, mysql, union

I'm trying to create a query which should show search suggestions.
The first query I execute is:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
    FROM shops
    WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%'
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY occurrences DESC, name
    LIMIT 5
```

This query is only selecting names which start with the search query.

For example search term 'wal' has the following results:

- **Wal** mart
- **Wal** store
- **Wal** ablala
- **Wal** lpaper store
- ...

If the above query has less then 5 results, it should do an extra query:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
    FROM shops
    WHERE name LIKE '%$queryString%'
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY occurrences DESC, name
    LIMIT 5
```

With results for search term 'wal':

- Paint **wal** ls
- Shopping **wal** l
- ...

So if the first query has 5 or more results, it should only display the first query. If it has less then 5 results, it should show a combination of both queries, something like:

- **Wal** mart
- **Wal** store
- **Wal** ablala
- **Wal** lpaper store
- Paint **wal** ls
- Shopping **wal** l
- ...

Note that it should first show the results of the first query, after that the results of the second query. I never want to show more then 5 results.

I think I need to use the UNION function somehow, but can't get it working.

Comment: This query showed results in wrong order: (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS occurrences FROM winkels WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%' GROUP BY name) union (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS occurrences FROM winkels WHERE name LIKE '%$queryString%' GROUP BY name) ORDER BY occurrences DESC, name LIMIT 10

Comment: And this one does not take the amount of occurrences into account: (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS occurrences FROM winkels WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%' GROUP BY name ORDER BY occurrences DESC, name) union (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS occurrences FROM winkels WHERE name LIKE '%$queryString%' GROUP BY name ORDER BY occurrences DESC, name) LIMIT 10

Answer (score 0):

The best way is you carry with UNION in stored procedures. As:

[UNION inside IF EXISTS statement not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415314/union-inside-if-exists-statement-not-working)

Comment: I've never used stored procedures. I'll take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many rows there are from the previous selection and limit the second select accordingly. Then you can limit the total results you want.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT name FROM shops WHERE name like '$queryString%'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT name FROM shops WHERE name LIKE '%$queryString%')
    LIMIT
    (5 - 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT name FROM shops WHERE name like '$queryString%'))
    )
) LIMIT 5;
```

Using joins is probably a better way to do it though if you want the occurrences to be taken into account.

Note that this is an insecure way of inserting variables into queries. You should use prepared statement and execute the variables onto the query.